# If time now is more than 3 hours since last update

Tags: php

I need to have a validation that checks if the "last_update" is done before 3 hours or less.

I have this PHP code:

```
if($user['last_update'] < strtotime("3 hours")) {
    $msg .= "You can only register every 3 hour.";
}
```

How could this be done?

Comment: what is format of `$user['last_update']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$user['last_update']` is in date format, then

```
if (time() - strtotime($user['last_update']) < 3 * 3600) {
  //..
}
```

Comment: In fact if a `strtotime` recognizable date format it'll work.

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfect! The $user['last_update'] is in unix time so I just removed the strtotime() , thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this. Wrap your **`$user['last_update']`** inside **`strtotime()`**.

```
if(strtotime($user['last_update']) < strtotime("3 hours")) {
    $msg .= "You can only register every 3 hour.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get the current time minus 3 hours:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$dateTime->modify("-3 hours");

$time = $dateTime->format("H:m:s");
$date = $dateTime->format("Y-m-d");
```

You can then compare the date and time variables with your last update.

Comment: Are you referring string comparison?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im no, they are a php date object and a php time object

Comment: `$date` and `$time` are strings. If you want OP to compare them with other variable, aren't you referring string comparison with `<` sign? In that case, its a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime()`

returns seconds.

If your date is stored as UNIX timestamp, then your code is correct.
If your date is stored as TIMESTAMP, following will be the code:

```
$three_hours = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('3 hours'));
if ($user['last_update'] < $three_hours) {
    $msg .= "You can only register every 3 hour.";
}
```